# Memory Leak in a list of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a list of pointers to objects.

```
 std::list<X*> xList;
```

All I need is the size of the list so my method, populates this list and calls size() on it and then returns the size.

NOTE: I know this is not the best solution, but I am using an API that provides a list with dynamically allocated objects and this is the only way I can do it.

Now valgrind is saying that there's memory leaks here. I am assuming that this is because I never delete the objects that are in the list.

I thought I'll do this:

```
std::list<X*>::iterator iter;
for (iter = xList.begin(); iter != xList.end(); ++iter)
{
    delete (*iter);
}
```

but is this the best solution to this?

Comment: Using a smart pointer would be a better solution.

Comment: I think you can not delete elements this way (while iterating using that iterator).

Comment: @dbrank0: Deleting the object referenced by the iterator is perfectly fine.

Comment: Why are you filling the list if you just need the size?  Why not just count the number of times you would have added an item?

Comment: If all you need is the size, why are you populating a list full of dynamically allocated objects?

Comment: This is a *really* weird problem description: "All I need is the size of the list"... why? What for? Why not just have a simple counter?

Comment: Guys I am using an API that I did not write, this is what I have to work with :)

Comment: Whoever down voted, care to explain?

Comment: It could be related to "All I need is the size of the list so my method, populates this list and calls size() on it and then returns the size..." If this is true, it is not clear what the point of the dynamic allocation is at all.

Comment: but it's true, all I need is the size and I have an API (that I did not write) that returns me a list of objects. I have no other way around this. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the API returns you a list of dynamically allocated objects that you are responsible for de-allocating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the best solution would be to have a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<X>>` instead. Now the objects will delete themselves as and when it's appropriate, and you do not have to concern yourself with it. When the `std::list` is destroyed, the `X` objects which are owned by it are also destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

> but is this the best solution to this?

No, the best solution would be to have a `std::list<std::shared_ptr<X> >` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kam do you know what a smart pointer is? `std::shared_ptr`? Look it up. It provides automatic memory management for dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: Ah sorry yes I understand, I wanted to know why you have chosen a shared_ptr specifically for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Kam in case ownership is shared. No other reason. Use a `unique_ptr` if you can.