# C++ Memory Leak using list class and push_back

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, memory-leaks, destructor

C++ Memory Leak using list class and push_back

```
void EMAdd(int n)
{
   list<Employee*> em;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      em.push_back(new Employee());
}
```

Q1. at the end , the destructor of class list automatically deletes the nodes of em?

Q2. But why this function still has a memory leak?

Thanks,
I would appreciate your answer!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584815/memory-leak-in-a-list-of-pointers-to-objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The destructor of `Employee` is *not* called. You have a `list` of *pointers* to `Employee` objects, not a list of `Employee` objects. When the list's destructor is called it will destroy the pointers to the `Employee` object, but not the objects they point to which you created with `new Employee()`. They will still be in memory but the only references to them are lost when the list is destroyed, leaking that memory.

Remember every call to `new` must have a matching call to `delete` somewhere.  However, better yet don't use pointers at all and simply use a list of `Employee` objects directly.

```
void EMAdd(int n)
{
   list<Employee> em;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      em.push_back(Employee());
}
```

Since each element in `std::list` is already dynamically allocated, a list of pointers is redundant and essentially gives you a set of pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `list` of `unique_ptr`s so that the memory will be freed upon destruction:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> em;
```

But as David Brown said, you shouldn't be using pointers to begin with.

Comment: This works, but each list element is already independently dynamically allocated, so a list of `unique_ptr<T>` is kind of redundant.

Comment: @DavidBrown Never mind I get what you mean. He shouldn't have pointers to begin with.